# Cannot reload model after BatchNorm config edit in Keras

Tags: python, keras, batch-normalization

I'm trying to modify a Keras's built-in pre-trained DenseNet121 to fine-tune it to another dataset. The current configuration of its BatchNorms won't allow me to get adequate predictions at test time, so I've decided to play with its momentum/scale/center/trainable parameters. *Momentum* and *trainable* could be modified through config changing and model saving/reloading with weights. *Scale*/*center*, however, couldn't be modified since Keras refuses to load weights:

```
ValueError: Layer #3 (named "conv1/bn") expects 3 weight(s), but the saved weights have 4 element(s).
```

A brief look into BatchNorms source code revealed that it has different number of parameters with different flags set:

```
def build(self, input_shape):
        ...

        if self.scale:
            self.gamma = self.add_weight(shape=shape,
                                         name='gamma',
                                         initializer=self.gamma_initializer,
                                         regularizer=self.gamma_regularizer,
                                         constraint=self.gamma_constraint)
        else:
            self.gamma = None
        if self.center:
            self.beta = self.add_weight(shape=shape,
                                        name='beta',
                                        initializer=self.beta_initializer,

             regularizer=self.beta_regularizer,
                                        constraint=self.beta_constraint)
        ...
```

And due to the weights shapes mismatch I cannot reload them.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way to load old weights to the model with modified BatchNorms center/scale parameters?
2. A question preceding the first one - what is the correct thing to do with the built-in model while fine-tuning, if its BatchNorm default configuration leads to the awful performance in test time? I've seen a lot of GitHub issues/StackOverflow question threads, but solutions were very different and didn't produce any kind of a solid approach.

Comment: What changes did you made to the weights? We cannot guess that, so the question is unanswerable as it stands.

Comment: Thanks for response. I haven't changed weights at all, I've changed the BatchNorm layers's parameter _scale_ to forbid the layer to multiply normalized batch by _gamma_. To apply changes (which were made in the model config, not in the model itself), I've saved the model config and reloaded it again (to get the actual changed model), and tried to load saved weights back. It appeared that that's not possible due to the different expected weight matrix size - that is illustrated by the code fragment in the main post.